# Get Jedis work with JMeter Engine

Tags: java, maven, redis, jmeter, jedis

I want to use the API provided by Apache JMeter to create and run test scripts from a Java program to test a Redis server using Jedis plugin. 
I have 2 pieces of code: to create and run a JMeter test plan and some Jedis commands that I wanna actually to be executed. And I have no clue how to combine them together. Please advice how I can include these Jedis commands to be executed in the JMeter test plan:

== JMeter code ==

```
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // jmeter.properties
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:/tmp/jmeter.properties");

        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();     

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);

        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");

        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);       

        jm.configure(hashTree);

        jm.run();
```

== Jedis code ==

```
    private static final String LOCAL_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 6379;

    private final JedisPool m_jedisPool;
    private Jedis m_jedis;

    m_jedisPool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), LOCAL_HOST, PORT)

    void test() {
            m_jedis = m_jedisPool.getResource();
            m_jedis.flushAll();

            // Run test
           Jedis jedis = getExistingJedisInstance();
           jedis.set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE).equals("OK");

            // After test;
            m_jedis.close();
            m_jedisPool.destroy();
        }
```

P.S. I know about Redis Data Set plugin, but it doesn't work for me since it doesn't support set commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put your Jedis code there (just make sure you have all the necessary dependency .jars in the classpath)

The relevant code to add the sampler to the Test Plan programatically would look something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.ScriptingTestElement;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;


public class JedisExample {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        File jmeterHome = new File("c:/apps/jmeter");
        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");

        //JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        JSR223Sampler jedisSampler = new JSR223Sampler();
        jedisSampler.setName("Jedis Sampler");
        jedisSampler.setProperty("script", "def LOCAL_HOST = \"localhost\"\n"
                + "def PORT = 6379\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "def m_jedisPool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), LOCAL_HOST, PORT)\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "def m_jedis = m_jedisPool.getResource()\n"
                + "m_jedis.flushAll()\n"
                + "\n"
                + "// Run test\n"
                + "def jedis = getExistingJedisInstance()\n"
                + "jedis.set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE).equals(\"OK\")\n"
                + "\n"
                + "// After test\n"
                + "m_jedis.close()\n"
                + "m_jedisPool.destroy()");
        jedisSampler.setProperty("scriptLanguage", ScriptingTestElement.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE);
        jedisSampler.setProperty("cacheKey", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        jedisSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSR223Sampler.class.getName());
        jedisSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());

        // Loop Controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        // Thread Group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Jedis Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        // Test Plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Jedis Test Plan");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(jedisSampler);

        // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + slash + "jedis.jmx"));

        //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
        // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        // Store execution results into a .jtl file
        String logFile = jmeterHome + slash + "jedis.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        // Run Test Plan
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

        System.out.println("Test completed. See " + jmeterHome + slash + "jedis.jtl file for results");
        System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + slash + "jedis.jmx");
        System.exit(0);


    }

}
```

References:

- [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Groovy Documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/documentation.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri! trying to get this code working :)

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Your advice to use JSR223 Sampler helped me a lot! And now I'm struggling with another issue. My goal is to get latency and throughput  logged into file for each transaction and then have a summary per each scenario with averages and max/min values for latency and throughput.

Comment: Currently I have this code:         String csvLogFile = JMETER_REPORTS_HOME + testName + "-summary.csv";
        ResultCollector csvlogger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        csvlogger.setFilename(csvLogFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], csvlogger));

Comment: But in this way it logs info only per one transaction and there is no throughput and latency reported is simply 0 (without any decimal part). Do you know is there any way how I can configure it?

Comment: I answered your question regarding 2 code bits integration, what to do next is totally up to you. For latency check out [SampleResult.setLatency()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setLatency-long-) method (you will need to calculate the value yourself). Throughput should be there already as JMeter calculates it automatically.